# How to block a contact on WhatsApp based on local time?

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, calls, google-pixel

I am trying to avoid getting WhatsApp calls from specific people who live on the other side of the world - when it's daytime for them, it's nighttime for me. Talking to them about it hasn't helped.

How do I block a contact on WhatsApp (on a Pixel 5, if it matters) only for a certain time window?

Comment: Interesting use case. I am not a developer but Whatsapp doesn't allow access to it's internal working through an API or any other way that can be exploited to do what you wish to do. Simplest IMO is to disable data (both mobile and Wifi) in that time slot. This process needn't be manual, it can likely be automated but it needs root or elevated privileges to the automation app using `ADB`

Comment: Or try an app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.callcenter.whatsblock.call.blocker) that claims to block calls on schedule. There are plenty of such apps on Play store. I haven't used any

Comment: @beeshyams Disabling data would mean I am blocking everyone. I still want to be able to receive (urgent) WhatsApp calls from only some of my contacts. Not leaning towards installing another app for this at the moment.